# How to manage local/staging/live url's in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my server side apps, I use .local files to store variables for each of my server environments: local, staging and live. Essentially, all I do is drop a file into the configs of each environment and the job is done.

Now I am finding I am doing more and more javascript related work and I have as of yet not figured out the strategy to manage the variables for the different environments.

As an example, my JS code for my local environment will be:

```
$('#login-spin').addClass('fa-spin');

    var url ='http://cloud-local.example.com/api/login';

    $.ajax({
    type:  'POST',
    data : JSON.stringify({
        'email' : email,
        'password' : password
    }),
```

**My staging will use this url:**

```
var url ='http://cloud-staging.example.com/api/login';
```

**And my live environment will use:**

```
var url ='http://cloud.example.com/api/login';
```

I use git to manage my code and to deploy to the different environments is a matter of: git push staging/live

With the current method, I am going to need to change the links manually which is not great.

One solution is to store the url's in a server side file and use ajax to load the variables...

**What is best practice for this?**

Comment: Are these URLs even “external”, or are they the ones you run the whole app from? If the latter, might be less hassle to just use relative URLs, instead of absolute ones …

Comment: In this case I can in fact use relative url's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have finally come up with a strategy for my js code.

As per CBroe's suggestion, I am using relative url's where possible. However, in some cases this is not possible as I have to talk to external url's which may live on different environments. So in this case, I have created a constants.local.js service, added a .gitignore file to ignore the local file. Added a dist folder with a copy of the local file in it.

Now as I set up different server environments, I copy the dist file with relevant settings.

Initially I thought I could do this with some clever switch however, I believe it is best to code this as required.